# Migrating local images to database in Laravel

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5, image-uploading

I'm trying to seed my local images(.jpg) to database, but when i tried to display the images on my website its not showing every other fields works but the image. I guess i may have set the path wrongly. Please can anyone help to fix this issue?

[MigrationTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdZ9P.jpg)

[Product.Php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbIOH.jpg)

[ProductTableSeeder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqX4Y.jpg)

[div-form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96YQI.jpg)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k58w3.jpg)

Comment: shouldn't `imagePath` be `/public/FrontEnd/images/jj.jpg` instead of the mixture of forward and back slashes?

Comment: I tried it that way but it did not work.

Comment: It's been a while so I can't remember, but do you need the `public` part in the url or does Laravel automatically look there? Could be worth a try removing it.

Answer (score 0):

check that exemple :

```
$path = storage_path('app/public/photo');

                            $filename = sprintf('%s_%s_%s_Tracking', time(), $lastID, $newOffers->Name_offre);
                            $file->move($path, $filename.'.'.$extension);

                            $imageTracking= new ImageTracking();

                            $imageTracking->offers_id = $lastID;
                            $imageTracking->imageTracking = $filename.'.'.$extension;
                            $imageTracking->save();
```